# Memory used but not reported on Linux

Tags: linux, memory-usage

I have 2 servers running the same applications, but one is miss-reporting memory by around 400mb (out of 1GB) and I cannot figure out where that memory is being used. I've compared the output of `/proc/meminfo` and `top` between both servers and they report very similar memory usage (process wise), but one one has around 400 less memory available.

As a comparison, this is the output of free on this server and the other, where it shows a ~450mb of ram difference.

```
# Server with missing memory
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            957         707          85           0         164         107
Swap:             0           0           0

# Other server, looking good
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            953         224         210           0         518         553
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Here's the output of `/proc/meminfo`

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:         980756 kB
MemFree:           89020 kB
MemAvailable:     108824 kB
Buffers:           32440 kB
Cached:            96944 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           196416 kB
Inactive:          61448 kB
Active(anon):     128888 kB
Inactive(anon):      124 kB
Active(file):      67528 kB
Inactive(file):    61324 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:               656 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        128488 kB
Mapped:            57032 kB
Shmem:               524 kB
Slab:              78228 kB
SReclaimable:      37016 kB
SUnreclaim:        41212 kB
KernelStack:        2896 kB
PageTables:         7956 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      490376 kB
Committed_AS:    1099792 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      444392 kB
DirectMap2M:      575488 kB
DirectMap1G:           0 kB
```

And the output of top (sorted by memory usage)

```
top - 09:35:16 up 706 days, 11:49,  1 user,  load average: 0.15, 0.03, 0.01
Tasks: 124 total,   1 running,  82 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :   980756 total,    87896 free,   726108 used,   166752 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.   108060 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
 6348 ubuntu    20   0  582484  35120  13156 S   0.0  4.1   0:07.42 node
14394 root      20   0  439088  19760   2692 S   0.3  3.0 695:53.01 python
 2557 root      19  -1  124824  19424   7956 S   0.0  2.0  75:05.85 systemd-journal
24174 ubuntu    20   0   25932   7904   3384 S   0.0  0.8   0:00.08 bash
  724 root      20   0  170944   7844     12 S   0.0  0.8   0:00.15 networkd-dispat
24089 root      20   0  107988   6820   5820 S   0.0  0.7   0:00.01 sshd
14402 root      20   0   35268   5960   1952 S   0.0  0.6   7:38.52 python
14404 root      20   0   34748   5520   2060 S   0.0  0.6   6:34.19 python
14403 root      20   0   33512   5000   1684 S   0.0  0.5   0:57.69 python
24173 ubuntu    20   0  108344   4672   3548 S   0.3  0.5   0:00.04 sshd
14407 root      20   0   33508   4408   1104 S   0.0  0.4   0:35.97 python
14408 nobody    20   0   35616   4388   1000 S   0.0  0.4   1:54.36 python
    1 root      20   0  225416   4348   1876 S   0.0  0.4   3:45.45 systemd
  704 root      20   0   71304   4032   2500 S   0.0  0.4   0:56.31 systemd-logind
24594 ubuntu    20   0   42240   3656   2984 R   0.0  0.4   0:00.02 top
```

And the output of `mount | grep tmp` to show the any memory used by these filesystems. The main filesystem is ext4 (so no XFS)

```
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=478348k,nr_inodes=119587,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=98076k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=98072k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

The server has been running for almost 2 years and it's due a restart (which I think will make the issue go away) but I would like to figure out the missing ~400mb are.

## edit

Here's the reduced output of `systemd-cgtop -m` from both servers. The healthy one looks like is using more memory, but this is not the case!

```
# unhealthy server
Control Group                        Tasks   %CPU   Memory  Input/s Output/s
/                                      181    2.0   250.1M        -        -
/system.slice                           91    1.3   188.3M        -        -
/user.slice                             26    0.7   104.1M        -        -
/system.slice/logging-agent.service     11    1.1    40.5M        -        -
/system.slice/mycustom.service           7      -    34.6M        -        -

# healthy server
Control Group                        Tasks   %CPU   Memory  Input/s Output/s
/                                      187    2.6   655.7M        -        -
/system.slice                           95    1.4   446.6M        -        -
/user.slice                             24    1.1   287.5M        -        -
/system.slice/cron.service               1      -   238.3M        -        -
/system.slice/mycustom.service           7      -    43.7M        -        -
/system.slice/logging-agent.service     11    1.3    40.0M        -        -
```

Comment: Why do you think memory is missing? Total matches used+free+cached on both servers. One of the servers just has less used memory so the kernel uses more RAM for disk cache.

Comment: Hi Mikko this was a long time ago, so I hope my recollection is still ok. The "problem" was that the unhealthy server reported 700mb of memory used (as taken from `free`) but I couldn't see the 700mb used by applications, but rather saw ~250-300mb being used. This happened on a server that had been running for 2+ years without a reboot and a switch off and on fixed it.

Comment: Okay, sounds like it was a small memory leak in the kernel which isn't unheard of for old kernels.

Answer (score 2):

Less than 1 GB RAM for a VM is not a lot these days. `MemAvailable` is 11% of `MemTotal`, which isn't a large margin. A mere 60 MB more to get to a round 1024 MB would reduce pressure  a bit. I base this off of `Comitted_AS`.

But that doesn't tell where precisely the memory allocations are made. And `top` isn't as helpful as you might think, RES will not add up neatly due to shared pages and other unintuitive things. A tip for top: hit `c` to toggle a full command line. A huge number of programs use python or node, you'll want to tell them apart.

On Linux, use cgroups to measure. On systemd systems, enable memory accounting and look at `systemd-cgtop -m`. Should be apparent whether user or service slices are allocating more memory. Either is plausible. And a few hundred MB difference is not a lot in absolute numbers, a couple extra worker jobs or a stray user login could add up to that.

---

> The server has been running for almost 2 years and it's due a restart

Overdue. Guaranteed there are security updates that have not taken effect. Record `/proc/meminfo` and `systemd-cgtop` metrics, update, and reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer John. I ran `systemd-cgtop -m`, but it didn't give me much information... in fact, the healthy server looks like it's using far more memory (I've updated the question with the output of the command)

Comment: By what metric is that an unhealthy host, are the applications slow for users? You can spend an enormous amount of time chasing a few hundred MB. Which does not seem worthwhile if you meet performance objectives. Not even anything super bad in meminfo or top.  I suspect the workload and system processes on these hosts aren't as identical as you think.